# GitHub "Failed to publish this branch" error on Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, repository

I'm new to Git, and I just downloaded it yesterday.  As a test for my first online (not local) repository, I committed a useless text file and then hit publish.  After a short while, I got this very non-descriptive error:

[image]

So I know that I can't publish to this branch.  There's only one and it's the master branch.  Is there any further information on what might be causing this error?

As a side note, my partner has successfully uploaded files to the same repository, but I haven't gotten any sort of indication that this has happened.  Does this mean I'm not connected to the repository properly in some way?  I was the one who set it up!

Comment: Hi, open the terminal, and type `git push`. You'll then have a much clearer error message.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Do you know how I would do this on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes, with your favourite command line (work mostly the same everywhere). In Github for windows you have the option to open a terminal directly in the project folder.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Windows, right click on your *repository* → click on *Open a shell here*.

You will see a command prompt.

Type `git push` in it. (been aware after seeing SimonBoudrias comment)

The command prompt will suggest you to type some other command or shows an error.

If the command prompt suggest you to type something else, then type that. It will work. 
If the command prompt shows an error, then please post the detailed error here.

**Information**: You might want to check [this app](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck)

Comment: I did what you said, and I get the error:`To https://github.com/Kill-Console/RegexTester.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Kill-Console/RegexTester.
git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: Read the error - it says "You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g. 'git pull...') before pushing again.

Comment: After trying `git push` it suggested I try `git push --set-upstream origin master` which I did but then I got the error: `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/username/evolution.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error`. (By the way evolution is the name of the repo.) So what should I do now?

Comment: Switch to SSH.  In the command line tool... git remote set-url origin git@github.com:myname/myrepo.git

Comment: If you need to do a pull first, try  git pull <your git url>.git, then do the push again

Comment: This resolved my issues as with others above, in order to get the GitHub desktop to properly understand those changes it just needed a simple restart then Syncing worked properly.

Answer (score 11):

Open a `shell` in your repository. Then type

```
git push --set-upstream origin master --force
```

This will upload your local repo to the server no matter what, `overwriting` if necessary. This **should only be done if you're sure nobody else is publishing to your repo** at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue as mentioned here, but none of the previous solutions helped. Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github#18356572) which talks about *Proxy settings*, which is exactly why GitHub was failing to commit on my machine.

To set up your proxy settings, you just need to use this command:

```
git config --global http.proxy http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is a **temporary unavailability of GitHub servers**.

I'm just having the same problem and confirmed that it's a server issue: https://status.github.com/

Sample screenshot:

[image: GitHub temporarily down]

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, open a command prompt in the repository. For example, by pressing the cog in the top right in the repo view and selecting "open a shell here".

- In the command prompt, type `git push --set-upstream origin master`
- Either this will work, or it will say `! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first)`
- If this happens, type `git pull origin master` (add --rebase if you like)

In GitHub, the *Publish* button might still be visible instead of the sync button. If this is the case, simply restart GitHub.

This resets the default remote branch for your local branch to master.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just forget type something to the Description area when you commit your files.  Someone like me only type the summery. So make sure you have fill in the Summary and **Description** when you commit.

Just type something to the *Description* textarea when committing. Then I published successfully.

What I do:

1. Go to the folder of your repository in Windows Explorer
2. Delete the file your want to publish. And recreate it.
3. Open GitHub for Windows and click on your repository. Then you will find *Uncommitted changes* on the left side.
4. Type your *Summary*
5. Type your *Description* (the most important step!)
6. Commit to *master*
7. Hit *Publish* and you should be successful.

This is my first answer. so i have no 10 reputation to post an image......hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error since I forgot to add a remote repository link in the [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/). Once I added the correct repository link, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to commit your changes before publishing. It helps me to solve same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem while publishing my GitHub page. I solved it in the following way.

```
git push
```

I got the error message here. Then I made a pull request

```
git pull
```

After this I made the push again

```
git push
```

Here I got the solution.

Note: I use GitHub for Windows. And I finally published the page using it

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error because I hadn't properly configured my name and email. On the page where you do that (in the native app, at least), you'll see that the page opens with your name and email already filled in but that doesn't mean that they're saved as settings. In order to save them, you have to press the check mark in the bottom left corner of that screen.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where a screenshot would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I already had created a repository with the same name on GitHub, and then created it locally and tried to commit it.  The solution was to delete it from GitHub, then commit it from the local client.  Now they're in sync.