# GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error

Tags: git, github

I installed Git to get the latest version of Angular. When I tried to run

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
```

I got:

> failed to connect to github 443 error

I even tried

```
git clone git://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
```

That gave me

> failed to connect no error message

I am behind my company firewall. I can not see my proxy details when I go to *Control Panel* → *Internet Options* → *Connections* → *LAN setting*. The IT guys are not sharing proxy information with me. What can do?

---

I finally managed to do it. I will update the procedure that I had taken in order to.
I just wanted to compile all the steps that I did to get it to work.

Comment: See this question on how to setup a proxy with git on Windows http://stackoverflow.com/q/16153450/579234

Comment: I realised that this can happen too if you just spam github with push requests from the terminal. And yes I realised that while inconsiously spamming.
Edit: It has nothing to do with the proxy settings, but you can still get a 443 error.

Comment: If u have socks5 proxy, simply use `git config --global http.proxy 127.0.0.1:1080` where 127.0.0.1 is the proxy URL, 1080 is the port.

Comment: On Windows, presumably. But what command line environment? [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway)? Cmd? [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)? [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)? [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)?

Comment: What are the actual literal error messages?

Comment: Something like "`Failed to connect to github.com port 443: `"?

Comment: Related: *[Getting Git to work with a proxy server - fails with "Request timed out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/)*

Answer (score 426, accepted):

Well, I did the following steps

1. Google the error
2. Got to SO links ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496277/git-error-fatal-unable-to-connect-a-socket-invalid-argument), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512202/github-https-access)) which suggested the same thing that I have to update the Git configuration for proxy setting
3. Damn, I can not see proxy information from Control Panel. The IT guys must have hidden it. I can not even change the setting to not to use a proxy.
4. I found [this wonderful tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using) of finding which proxy your are connected to
5. Updated the `http.proxy` key in the Git configuration by the following command

   ```
   git config --global http.proxy http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port
   ```
6. Error - "could not resolve proxy `some@proxyaddress:port`". It turned out my password had a `@` symbol in it.
7. Encode `@` in your password to `%40`, because Git splits the proxy setting by @
8. If your userName is an email address, which has `@`, also encode it to `%40`. (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40478893/4910876))

   ```
    git config --global http.proxy http[s]://userName(encoded):password(encoded)@proxyaddress:port
   ```

Baam! It worked!

Comment: How is this encoding done. Could you translate `http://johndoe:f@tm@n@example.com:80` into the encoded version, please? The last `@` need not be encoded

Comment: its very simple %40 is url encoded value of @, so replace all your @ in your password with %40. I guess "f@tm@n" is your password in the string that you wrote above. So it would become f%40tm%40n

Comment: does this encoding apply to domains too? Where the username is `mydom\me` making the string `http://mydom\me:f%40tm%40n@example.com:80`

Comment: Sidenote:  Splitting the credentials from the url using `@` is not unique to github.  This is actually [part of the url standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/url/#find-the-user-info,-host,-and-port).

Comment: @Anand: What is the user name and password here?. Is it the credential required for Proxy server or is it the credential required for GitHub?

Comment: that user name and password is for the proxy. Generally its your username and password which you use to login in to your office account

Comment: Unless your proxy requires a username and password, you don't need the "userName:password@" portion.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to appears to be windows only - is there a linux alternative?

Comment: @Anand But I am not even on a proxy server, then what should I do to fix this error? What do I put in the proxy server? I am not using any proxy

Comment: @Anand. Thanks for your explanation. i had an @ symbol in my password and your details explanation helped me.

Comment: If you setup a local CNTLM proxy you can store your password encrypted too. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18618941/579234

Comment: Sometimes the proxy does not need a password (you are inside of your firm network that has internet acess via a proxy-server), then you just put `git config --global http.proxy <host:port>`  (you found the latter in the tutorial).

Comment: + to easily find your proxy: go to http://wpad/wpad.dat and then in downloaded file look at proxyServer

Answer (score 73):

If your Git installing was already set to something and you only copied that folder to some other location, simply run:

```
git config --global http.proxy ""
```

And Git will set itself straight. After what, you can pull again :)

Comment: helpful github desktop link https://help.github.com/desktop-classic/faq/articles/can-i-log-in-behind-a-proxy-server/

Answer (score 36):

If your country or working environment blocks sites like Github.

Then you can build a proxy, e.g. use [xxnet](https://github.com/XX-net/XX-Net), which is free & based on Google's `GAE`, and available for `Windows` / `Linux` / `Mac`.

Then set proxy address for git, e.g:

```
git config --global http.proxy 127.0.0.1:8087
```

Answer (score 25):

Mine was fixed by just using this command:

```
git config --global http.proxy XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:ZZ
```

where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the proxy server address and ZZ is the port number of the proxy server.

There wasn't any need to specify any username or password in my case.

Comment: worked! also support socks5 proxy, my cmd is `git config --global http.proxy 127.0.0.1:1080`

Answer (score 23):

If you are not using a proxy and are still facing this issue, you should use the below command line:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Simply hit this command, and this will fix the issue.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Worked for me but still don't know the damaged or the desadvantages

Answer (score 17):

I got so:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://{domain}\\\{username}:{password}@{proxy ip}:{proxy port}

git config --global http.sslverify false
```

Comment: Two slashes for me not three: `{domain}\\{username}`

Answer (score 16):

---

Option 1 : Windows specific

```
Restart your machine
```

---

Option 2 : Unset your proxy

```
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Comment: For me it was "bounce my internet router" (phone in my case) LOL

Comment: For me, restarting my windows PC fixed it. Could it be a memory issue that caused it? I've ran some programs that used up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 13):

I have wide experience working with corporate proxies.

If you have configured the proxy and it's impossible to work with Git (always getting a 443 error), try to check if you have a *remote.origin.proxy* bypassing your configuration.

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

If you check that "remote.origin.proxy" is configured as an empty value, try to unset it or almost set it with your corporate proxy:

```
git config --add remote.origin.proxy "http://[yourproxy]:[yourport]"
```

And since several enterprise sites have untrusted certificates, I recommend you to avoid certificate checking if you are using [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security):

```
git config http.sslverify false
git config --global http.sslverify false
```

Comment: Something seems to be missing near *"working well with"*.

Answer (score 11):

The same problem happened to me in Windows using [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/).

I set a proxy setting as usual:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:pass@proxy.com:port
```

In my situation, the username is email, so it has a @ sign.
After ***encoding the *@* sign with *%40**** in the username, the problem is resolved.

So, encode the special characters not only in the password, but also in the username. (Refer to the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999/4910876).)

Comment: but after adding gobal proxy , connection is getting refused from my work repo  , it is not getting connected 443 error

Answer (score 7):

`ipconfig /renew` - solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error in [Sourcetree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements).

Go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Network* and check **Add proxy server configuration to Git/Mercurial** if you had already set the proxy settings.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 7, setting the proxy to the global configuration will resolve this issue

```
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy_addr:port
```

But the problem here is your password will not be encrypted... Hopefully that should not be much problem as most of time you will be the sole owner of your PC.

Comment: To encrypt password, use CNTLM, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18618941/579234

Comment: if you set the Proxy to http://user@proxy_addr:port, simply omitting the Password, git will work, giving you a Login prompt for your Proxy server when you connect.  That works quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was solved using this command

```
git config --global http.proxy http://login:password@proxyServer:proxyPort
```

Answer (score 2):

If using an SSH configuration file, my issue was that the *`~/.ssh/config`* file was not specified correctly. From *[Enabling SSH connections over HTTPS](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port#enabling-ssh-connections-over-https)*:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm behind a proxy in Windows 10 (and in Windows 11), `git 2.32.0.window.1`. This is what worked for me.

#### Checking What You Have

Check your global configurations using:

```
git config --global --list
```

You should see the settings for `user.name`, `user.mail`, etc. Having the following lines in place fixed the problem for me:

```
http.proxyauthmethod=basic
http.proxy=http://username:password@proxyaddress:port
https.proxy=https://username:password@proxyaddress:port
```

Notice these are settings for both HTTP and HTTPS protocols. If you don't see both, you'll have to set them.

#### Setting The Proxy

Use this line of code in your console, for *both* protocols:

```
git config --global https.proxy https://username:password@proxyaddress:port
```

And, if necessary:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxyaddress:port`
```

If you don't know what the proxy and ports are, look for *Internet Options* (or properties) window menu in your Windows system (Control Panel).

*Internet Properties (window)* → *Connections* (tab) → *LAN Settings* (button) → *Proxy Server* (section) → *Advanced* (button)

And, remember to replace all values (id est: `username`, `password`, `proxyaddress`, and `port`) with the actual ones (in `proxyaddress` you'll have to set up an IP address).

Keep in mind that you may need to leave some of those values empties (because they are not required by your proxy). For example, one time I had to set:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://:@10.1.33.244:81
```

As you may noticed, no user name or password were needed.

#### Useful Bash script

Since I have to set and unset the proxy configuration of my system on a daily basis, I've made this little script you main find useful: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/carloswm85/3d22fb0337b5423989008204ec3a3981)

#### Note

If you need to access [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab), you may need to follow these steps after the ones I've just described: [GitLab authentication requires tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51133684/7389293)

When you try to clone the repository, you'll be prompted for your GitLab username and password. Instead of entering your regular password, you need to provide a generated token instead. The username is the same.

Comment: This gave me a "Unsupported proxy syntax in 'proxyaddress:port'."

Comment: @LukePerez probably it's a problem specific to your system. If you were the one downvoting the answer, please, remove it. It worked on my system. If it were a wrong solution in deed, we would need more people reporting it is, one case is not enough. Can you provide more information about your problem? That would be useful for finding a solution.

Comment: @BeauregardLionett Did you replace the words with the actual values? It should be `some ip number for proxy` and `port number`.

Comment: Probably, I've asked that in August last year though, can't remember now.

Comment: I remember solving it, can't recall how.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is a bit convenient, but none of the previous answers said it:

**Solution:**

I had to *unset* both `http.proxy` and `https.proxy`

```
git --global --unset http.proxy
git --global --unset https.proxy
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"What worked for me is a bit convenient"*?

Comment: What I meant was : I had to unset both http.proxy and https.proxy which was kind of tricky but I don't understand why @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 0):

I got an error when I used

```
<git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy_addr:port>
```

The error is that the configuration file cannot be identified as there isn't any such file. I changed the command to

```
<git config --system http.proxy http://user:password@proxy_addr:port>
```

I am running Git on the Windows 7 command prompt.
The above command references the configuration file in `GIT_HOME/etc/gitconfig`.
The `--global` option does not.

Comment: Are the brackets (`<>`) actually part of it? They aren't in the other answers. Can you elaborate (or change it)?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 4 years ago"*

Answer (score 0):

Before you try the fancy stuff, try disabling the firewall and antivirus and see if it works. That was my problem.

Comment: And then? To "make it work" may be insecure. What was the real problem?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have to set the `https_proxy` and `http_proxy` in addition to the Git proxy configuration. Only then did it work.

Answer (score 0):

Being in a corporate environment, "our" Git installation used a *gitconfig* file in its installation directory, not the standard *C:\users\<you>\.gitconfig* file.

This showed me where the gitconfig file was:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

I edited the file by adding these:

```
[remote "origin"]
    proxy = http://proxyserver:port
[http]
    proxy = http://proxyserver:port
[https]
    proxy = http://proxyserver:port
```

Also, my installation had

```
[credential]
    helper = manager
```

I can now get to external repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [MSYS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64#MSYS2) Git behind a firewall, and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19933588/7404323) works for me:

A very simple solution: replace https:// with git://

Answer (score 0):

I'm also on a company VPN connected to GitHub.
I ended up just using [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) and that didn’t have any problems.

It is definitely not a fix, but a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

I have [Git GUI](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui) installed on a Windows system behind a proxy. Issuing 'git clone' from a Linux virtual machine running on the Windows system works, but Git GUI yields the 443 error mentioned in the heading.

To fix this, one must edit %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig to add an *[http]* section:

```
[http]
    postBuffer = 1000000000
    proxy = the.proxy.address:the.proxy.port
    sslcainfo = C:/Users/username/Documents/the.certificate.name.cer
```

Note that the path to the security certificate file has had its backslashes ('\') replaced by slashes ('/').

Answer (score -1):

I am using [TortoiseGit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit) and simply go to *Git* in *Settings* and apply the same settings to *Global*. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio), go to menu *Tools* → *NuGet Package Manager* → *Package Manager Console*.

Type: *git config --global http.proxy http://xxx.xxxx.xxxx:Port*

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my issue by changing the [DNS name server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) to *8.8.8.8*. (pls note your cause may be different from mine, I just provide the solution to my issue here, may not work for you)

Comment: Which is Google's name server(?).

Comment: What was the real issue?

Answer (score -3):

If you are on Windows and not behind a proxy, simply restarting your machine may solve it.