# Clone failed unable to access "https://....." failed connect to github:443 no error

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-clone

I am using Android project and I'm sick of this error:

> `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/caddy2519/MyBabyGrowing.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error`

How do I fix this?

I don't use proxy server.

Comment: Can you access `https://github.com` from a web browser?

Comment: Yes.................................

Comment: Wow this is still unanswered question.

Comment: Maybe you do use a proxy server even if you are unaware of it. Try checking your connection (for example here: http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test) and see if your requests are not being handled by your ISP's proxy.

Comment: Please check the 443 is accessible. From git bash $ curl https://github.com:443 . From CMD on Windows $ telnet github.com 443

Comment: See the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)

Answer (score 1):

Check if your network is protected, if so, you can configure proxy for git provided in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999/1233686), as follows:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

- change proxyuser to your proxy user
- change proxypwd to your proxy password
- change proxy.server.com to the URL of your proxy server
- change 8080 to the proxy port configured on your proxy server

Otherwise, you should consider a fresh install of git.

Answer (score -1):

Remove Slash after .git(/)

> https://github.com/caddy2519/MyBabyGrowing.git/

Change it to

> https://github.com/caddy2519/MyBabyGrowing.git