# GIT clone issue with Windows

Tags: angularjs, git, http, clone, git-pull

I am in windows machine and trying to

**git clone --depth=14 https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git**

I got failed to connect to github 443 error

then I Updated the http.proxy key in git config by following command

**git config --global http.proxy http://mycompany.proxy.name/my-company.com/abc.pac**

Still its failing with following error

```
D:\>git clone --depth=14 https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
Cloning into 'angular-phonecat'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git/':   Failed connect to github.com:1080; No error
```

Any luck here ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your .netrc is incorrect or something?
Try removing the info from your .netrc and cloning first (since it's a public repo).

If it isn't a GitHub server issue, it could be your firewall.
And/or your proxy (`git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy:xxx`).

Also check: [GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)