# Git Failed to connect to github port 443 - some repository work, others dont

Tags: git, github

I have since some weeks a running setup of GIT under Ubuntu 14.04 using the following GitHub repository:

https://github.com/hacke1978/simpleTree

Today I wanted to perform a push after a commit getting:

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hacke1978/simpleTree/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

I cannot perform git push after successful commit, nor create a new clone of this repository.

cloning for example the point cloud library works yet fine:

git clone https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl

I triple checked:
The owner pw hacke1978 is still valid, I dont use any typos. I can log in into GitHub webpage just fine.

I reinstalled git after a purge it.

I rebootet.

That I can clone other public repositories makes me think, this is something wrong with my repository and not reasoned by university network (got this idea from :

[GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)

Any suggestions what to do other than recreating a new repository from my local code?

Comment: Try pushing with ssh. Generally, I get timeout issues intermittently with https when I try to clone via https. Add a remote with same url but use ssh and try to push

Answer (score 6):

GitHub is suffering from a DDoS attack https://status.github.com/