# Error "Failed to connect to github.com port 443"

Tags: git, push

I tried to push some changes to GitHub using `git push origin master`, but after some time it showed an error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/the-unbelievable/MiniGames.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out

I've just created that repository and have already committed twice. I'm connected to the Internet through home Wi-Fi and the OS is [Mac OS X v10.10.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Yosemite) (Yosemite).

Comment: Github, at the time of this question, is going through a DDOS.

Comment: I doubt very much that you really get that error message with that url...

Comment: @arkascha, I just copied that from terminal

Comment: OK, interesting. So it is not the frontend https server on their side but the internal ssh connection that fails. I would not have expected such an error is routed to the client by them... Sorry!

Comment: If not DDoS, possibly *[Getting Git to work with a proxy server - fails with "Request timed out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is continuous DDoS attack ...
https://status.github.com/messages

Comment: the page in the link is blank shows nothing

Comment: @ChangZhao That is because the link was from 8 years ago, Github at the time was undergoing a DDoS, this page used to be where you'd get status updates.

Answer (score 17):

If you are behind a proxy, check the content of `C:\Users\[your username]\.gitconfig` and make sure a proxy is configured:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://yourproxy.com:8080  // Change your settings here
[https]
    proxy = http://yourproxy.com:8080  // Change your settings here
```

Comment: If my repo url is https://csd.com/Demo/_git/Demo/ .. what will be proxy = in this case...

Comment: first of all this link is not working, but how can i find my proxy link ?? this is so ambigiuos

Answer (score 6):

From here:
[GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github/18356572#18356572)

```
git config --global http.proxy http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port
```

Where port might be 3128 and userName:password might be your windows login credentials

Comment: In my case repo url is csd.com/Demo/_git/Demo  and getting message Failed to connect to csd.com port 443: Timed out .. more over my pwd as @ in it.. can you please tell me what will be  http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port in my case...

Comment: Do you have username and passwrd for it? Then add them to your git config. Also, make sure you can ping the host and try to connect from another client. Your problem might not be related to this if you are not trying to connect to GitHub

Comment: Our entire team is having issues. This happens with VS 2017 only. VS 2015 is good. We are new azure devops. This happens with VS 2017 using Azure DevOps with Team Explorer

Comment: Have you tried to export settings from VS 2015 and inspect them? Can you try from different networks that does not require proxi? Lan and WiFi? Are you pointing to the same resources and same protocol? Same Azure subscription and same login (work/personal) and role? I assume is a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure the environment by using:

```
sudo vim.tiny /etc/environment
```

Add there:

```
http_proxy=http://your.proxy.server.address:port
https_proxy=http://your.proxy.server.address:port
ftp_proxy=http://your.proxy.server.address:port
```

Also add the proxy setup in the gitconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it using this command:

```
git config --global http.proxy http[s]://usrGithub:passwordGithub@ipProxy:portProxy
```

using the GitHub login username and password and the IP address and port that I have on my proxy