# Git push not working... Failed to connect with no error

Tags: git, github

I am trying to sync some changes to my git repo, but I am getting the following error (I hid the git repo name):

```
...\project [master]> git push
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/...(repo).git/': Failed connect to github.com:80; No error
```

The changes I want to commit have been committed but not synced (pushed) to the repo which is what I am trying to do...

I previously committed some changes successfully (using: git commit .) like I usually do every day, and now out of nowhere I start getting this error...

I tried syncing with the github application for windows, and I also get an error:

```
Failed to sync this branch
You might need to open a shell and debug the state of this repo.
```

I am stumped, can someone point out the obvious? - It has always worked, today it just doesnt seem to want to work...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333319/failed-to-connect-to-github-443

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is being DDOSed, Mykola was right...

https://status.github.com/messages

Thanks