# Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out

Tags: git, github

```
git clone https://github.com/RubyLouvre/avalon
Cloning into 'avalon'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/RubyLouvre/avalon/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

I can not use HTTPS to clone any repo, but I can clone them by SSH.

```
git clone git@github.com:RubyLouvre/avalon.git
Cloning into 'avalon'...
remote: Counting objects: 33102, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (44/44), done.
```

What is the problem with this? I even set proxy, but it is still not working. I try much of network environment, but it makes no sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333319/failed-to-connect-to-github-443

Comment: I have try these way,but it is still not working

Comment: Check your connection to network, the proxy, are you in  virtuals environment?

Comment: The network is well,real enviornment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to connect to github 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333319/failed-to-connect-to-github-443)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using proxy for network connection, then you will have to add proxy to git config file. Use the below command to add proxy.

```
git config --global http.proxy http[s]://username:password@proxyipaddress:portnumber
```

Answer (score -1):

try to check host and remove proxy for github

example:

```
# rm it
199.232.96.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
```