# git clone failed from Jenkins: port 443 operation timed out

Tags: git, jenkins

I am running a jenkins pipeline which is having 2 layered git repos.

1. Jenkins pipeline is in one repo from which pipeline is triggered.
2. once pipeline is triggered it clones repo from another git repo to perform some operations.

I am able to trigger the pipeline, it starts correctly but give me following error when it starts to perform checkout of another repo-

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<project-name>/<project>.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
[Pipeline] echo
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 128
```

any help or pointers what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account under which Jenkins process is running has access to a global git config where the proxy is defined ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48901840/6309))

And make sure there is no firewall rule preventing you to access internet from your Jenkins server.