# Error for crazyflie cloning from repository

Tags: git, crazyflie

I am getting started with crazyflie install and I'm at that point where I am cloning from the repository section (under Install from source) option. However even after installing git, I seem to get the error

```
amatthew@DESKTOP-CPNVCSE:~/sample-directory$ git clone https://github.com/bitcraze/crazyflie-lib-python.git
Cloning into 'crazyflie-lib-python'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/bitcraze/crazyflie-lib-python.git/': Failed to connect to 192.91.225.210 port 44 after 130542 ms: Connection timed out
```

I'm not sure why this keeps happening. I tried altering the proxy as suggested here, which is just another error that someone else ran into ([Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663299/failed-to-connect-to-github-com-port-443-operation-timed-out)), but that didn't work. It looks like I have a direct connection and no proxy has been interrupting the traffic. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: are you able to clone any other repo from github?

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste that error or type it in by hand? I ask because it says `192.91.225.210 port 44`, which looks problematic (it should be using port `443`).

Comment: @larsks I was just referring to an example that was on stack overflow, which states port 443. The error that I get states port 44. I am unable to clone any other repo from github