# Cannot use git or SSH when on cellular connection

Tags: git, ssh, remote-access, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-server

Long time reader, first question!
I have been developing using WSL (Ubuntu) and remote servers. Recently I got a sim card for my laptop for those long hours on the road. My issue is that I cannot use both git or SSH while on the cellular connection. For example, both of the commands below work on WIFI, but time-out on the cellular connection:

$ ssh new@sdf.org

> ssh: connect to host sdf.org port 22: Connection timed out

$ git pull

> fatal: unable to access 'GIT URL': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

I have been searching for a long time but could not find any information to this specific issue. Other internet access seems to work (e.g. "apt-get").

This must be a setting I need to set for the cellular connection specifically, but I am at a loss as where to look.

Any ideas would be most welcome!

A.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33437568/13126651 does this helps?

Comment: In addition to checking if the SIM network is setting up a proxy automatically (per @Jatin-Mehrotra's comment), I would also just try a `wsl --shutdown` and restart to see if the Hyper-V virtual NIC that WSL is running behind gets remapped to the correct Windows interface.

Answer (score 0):

If this is WSL2, there are *a lot* of issues around connectivity.
[microsoft/WSL issue 6427](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6427), for instance, suggests:

- testing the same WSL, converted (again, for testing) [to WSL1](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6427#issuecomment-759642086):

  ```
  wsl --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 1
  ```
- [Disabling the swap of the WSL2 VM](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5437#issuecomment-647161596):

```sh
%userprofile%\.wslconfig
[wsl2]
swap=0
```