# Unable to clone project from GitHub using SourceTree

Tags: git, github

Hi I have been trying to clone my Github repo to my laptop using SourceTree. However, I keep getting the following:

fatal: unable to access 'https://username@github.com/username/MainProject.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error

Completed with errors, see above.

Ps. my Internet is working fine. I have tried cloning this project using another laptop and it worked.Does anyone know the possible reasons why with this laptop (my laptop at work :( ) it does not work and any possible solution?

Comment: It says "failed to connect". Can you open the URL in a browser on the same laptop?

Comment: Yes It opened fine :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this similar post [GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github). This may help you but even if it isn't it sounds like a proxy issue or maybe some sort of firewall.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your link and found the solution. What is did was go toTools>Options>Network and check Add proxy server configuration to Git/Mercurial and it works! :D