# Github error: Failed to connect to 443 port

Tags: shell, github

I am trying to build appinventor locally on windows 7 using the following document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Xc9yt02x3BRoq5m1PJHBr81OOv69rEBy8LVG_84j9jc/pub#h.5p32kqx16c2d

I've downloaded all the software listed in section 3 and proceeded building the app inventor by cloning a git repository by running the following git command from a shell: git clone https://github.com/mit-cml/appinventor-sources.git

I keep getting the following error: failed to connect to github 443 error

I've tired doing a Google search and found this: [GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)

I'm not at all experienced in this field so I do not understand any of the solutions mentioned, could you please try and help me out by going through the best solution step by step?

I'm working in a company so I can't get the proxy like they mentioned or the firewall might be blocking it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a proxy you need to use to connect to the internet? Is `failed to connect to github 443 error` the **exact** error? If not you should include the **exact** error. I assume you can get to github in your browser correctly?

Comment: Yes, the problem was due to proxy and its fixed now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)

Comment: Etan, if you've read my description correctly then you would be able to see that I've mentioned that link and commented 'I don't understand any of those solutions'.

Comment: I did read it. That's where I got the link from. The fact that you didn't understand those answers doesn't change the fact that the answer presented here is **identical** to the answers presented there including the accepted answer there which even includes links to two other similar questions and answers on this site and one on https://superuser.com about how to find out your current proxy.

Comment: It was not my intention to create another question similar to the one existing but as I do not have 50 reputation score, I could not make any comments and I could not post my question in the thread you've mentioned. In situations like this, you should understand that users have no choice but to do what I did if you take a logical look at it. I got help from my IT support and they've helped me out.

Comment: Did I criticize you? Did I accost you for making a mistake? No. I indicated that this is a duplicate of the other question. A question you found. You responded to that by defending the fact that it isn't the same (when it is). I don't know what problem you had understanding [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18356572/258523) that you didn't have understanding [the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34022424/258523) but that isn't material to the fact that they are the same answer.

Comment: Again, if you read my description correctly then you would realise that it implies this question is in fact a duplicate but the solutions were not helpful to me. Under no circumstance did I defend myself that this question isn't the same so I think its quite unreasonable for you to make such assumption. Considering the above, I feel that your comment was unnecessary. Also, I got my IT support to help me out, otherwise I would still not understand the answer to this question.

Comment: Which comment of mine was unnecessary? The one where I flagged this as a duplicate so it could be marked as such officially so we don't have two questions for the same issue floating around? The one where I explained why I did that after you questioned my having done that? Or the one where I could not understand what in my previous two comments you were objecting to and tried to show, again, that it is a duplicate? I'm not sure what you want at this point. I flagged this question because that's how SO is supposed to work. I'm glad you got this working but we don't need to keep this for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are behind the corporate firewall and if all your requests goes through the proxy server then you must set the Git proxy first before running any get commands like pull, fetch and push commands.

To set the Git proxy for HTTP and HTTPS use the following Git commands in the git bash shell

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080

//Replace username with your proxy username
//Replace password with your proxy password
//Replace proxy.server.com with the proxy domain URL.
//Replace 8080 with the proxy port no configured on the proxy server.
```

Check [How to configure Git proxy](https://itsmycode.com/configure-git-proxy/) and [How to unset the Git Proxy](https://itsmycode.com/configure-git-proxy/) for more details

Comment: Thank you, I've asked my IT support and they've supplied all the information you mentioned and it works now!

Comment: whats the alternative to not have your password hardcoded on the git config file? thanks

Comment: maybe we need to use vpn instead of proxy its work for me , i just disable my proxy and turn on my vpn