# git clone https://XXX, but,Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused,Why?

Tags: git, github

[image: this the detail according to the picture]

```
$ git clone https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git
Cloning into 'AFNetworking'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

why? How to solve this problem, help, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a firewall problem?

Comment: @tripleee I used the Lantern to over the wall, so I don't know what's the real  problem, but, Will the firewall problem leads to the result? By the Way , I can use ssh like git clone git@XXX

Comment: Not properly a programming question anyway. You'll easily find dozens of basically duplicate questions, here and elsewhere.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, Maybe that's reason. But I replace my hosts file ,it works.Before I used the method replacing hosts file to over the wall, Maybe this is the real cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. My way to deal with this problem is:

1  .replacing the hosts file if you are over the wall by this method.Then,  you can access to github.com not using VPN software just replacing Hosts file.

2  .refresh DNS. for Mac you can try:

```css
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

3 .if not this cause ,you can try  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github),By the way, that link's method not solve my problem, I tried it,But it's not useful.

Maybe that can solve your problem.

Thanks stackOverFlow platform, and thanks @tripleee to help me.