# git clone can not work on my mac terminal

Tags: git-clone

> **larrybin** at **LarrydeMacBook-Pro** in **~/test_site** 
>   [$ git clone https://github.com/LarryBrin/coursera-test.git ] 
>   Cloning into 'coursera-test' ... 
>   Fatal unable to access 'https://github.com/LarryBrin/coursera-test.git/' : Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out

I have searched on Google and StackOverflow throughout, but cannot find the answer. Can you tell what the problem is?

Comment: Need to enter `git` instead of `https`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)

Answer (score 0):

Check with this.

```
git clone git@github.com:LarryBrin/coursera-test.git
```

If you use http first set proxy and check with above command:

```
git config --global http.proxy [Ip_Address]:[port_number]
```