# git push -u origin master fatal : Unable to access

Tags: git, github

when i am trying push to origin , after typing below command :

```
git push -u origin master

fatal : Unable to access 'https://github.com/jayaramarao/jayaportfolio.git'
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Time out
```

Comment: Sounds like a networking problem. Do you have to set up a proxy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you behind a proxy.

Set the proxy on your machine and it should work

```
 git config --global http.proxy <ip>:<port>
```