# git pull returns fatal: unable to access "..." Received HTTP code 0 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, proxy, fatal-error

I have an already configured git repo and I need to use proxy server to access internet.

When I send the command **git pull** without any git configured proxy (http(s).proxy) I get the following message:

```
fatal: unable to access "https://..." Failed to connect to ... port 443: Connection refused
```

I've tried with:

```
git config --global http.proxy host:port
git config --global https.proxy host:port
```

and I get the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access "https://..." Received HTTP code 0 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Then I tried with:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://host:port
git config --global https.proxy http://host:port
```

or

```
git config --global http.proxy https://host:port
git config --global https.proxy https://host:port
```

but I get the same error.

Could you help me?

Comment: Might be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999/5784831)? You can check settings with `git config --list --show-origin` to make sure you have what you expect. By the way: You need `http.proxy` which is the name of a variable.

Comment: @Christoph no, there's no one duplicate for any value.

Comment: What if you follow these steps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18356572/5784831)?

Comment: @Christoph The only one different step is to set "http://user:password@proxy:port" but I've asked to my IT team and our proxy have no authentication...

Comment: If you need further help, please be more specific about what you did exactly. To me it is also not clear what config settings you have (locally, globally).