# WebStorm can't connect to gitlab.com port 1080

Tags: import, runtime-error, gitlab, webstorm

I want to import my Project in GitLab to my Computer. I'm using WebStorm. I tried to clone this but I always receive this error:

> unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/myUser/test_app.git': Failed to
>   connect to gitlab.com port 1080: Timed out.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: how can i try without webstorm? Sry i'm new with import project from gitlab :(

Comment: i just tried but i got same error :(

Comment: am not good at these types of questions, but see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github) helps

Comment: thanks for your help me:D Its worked :D

Comment: okay. I did it :P