# Java project from GIT in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket

I have Eclipse Java project on windows machine. I have pushed this project to newly created project in `Bitbucket` repository.

Now I would like to get this project in another machine by using Eclipse with `eGit` plugin. I do

```
Import->Source git repository->BranchSelection->Local destination->Select wizard to use for importing objects->Import using New Project wizard->Select wizard (java project)-> Create Java project
```

Got error:

[image]

If I do `Import as general project` instead of `Import using New Project wizard` I'm getting Generic project with files from Git. But it is not Java project.

I suppose there is less complicated way of creating Eclipse Java Git project. What is the right way of doing that?

Comment: Step 1: Check out the project locally Step 2: Import project from local directory

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/github-failed-to-connect-to-github-443-windows-failed-to-connect-to-github, and also can be useful https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/117