# "Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out" when pushing to remote repository

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

I've 'googled' and 'stackoverflowed' so much but I haven't found a solution for my problem.

I'm on Ubuntu and try **for the first time** git.

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

and created an account on the website (and verified the email, everything is ok). Then I

```
git config --global user.name "<my_name_here>"
```

and

```
git config --global user.email "<my_email_here>"
```

Then I went to the website and created a public repository called `gittest` (I did not initialized with a README nor added licence or .gitignore). Then I

```
mkdir gittest
```

on my desktop and

```
cd /Desktop/gittest
```

Then:

```
echo "# gittest" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/<my_username>/gittest.git
```

and finally

```
git push -u origin master
```

And that's the tragedy:
by clicking enter after written `git push -u origin master` it does nothing and after (many) seconds it returns an error message:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com//gittest.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out

- How do I resolve? Please help

**EDIT**

If I

```
echo "$http_proxy"
```

or

```
echo "$https_proxy"
```

nothing happens (the terminal returns me an empty row).

Comment: Possible canonical question (37 answers): *[GitHub - failed to connect to github 443 windows/ Failed to connect to gitHub - No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356502/)*

Comment: Or perhaps this one (27 answers and 1,019 upvotes): *[Getting Git to work with a proxy server - fails with "Request timed out"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/)*

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a proxy, you need configure that:

```
http.proxy
```

Override the HTTP proxy, normally configured using the *http_proxy*, *https_proxy*, and *all_proxy* environment variables (see curl(1)).

In addition to the syntax understood by curl, it is possible to specify a proxy string with a user name, but no password, in which case Git will attempt to acquire one in the same way it does for other credentials. See gitcredentials(7) for more information. The syntax thus is [protocol://][user[:password]@]proxyhost[:port]. This can be overridden on a per-remote basis; see remote.<name>.proxy

Perfect!

For solving the “Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out” message we need to run:

git config --global http.proxy

http://domain.local\username:password@proxyServer:8080

where username is your username in proxy and password is your password

Done! You can check if the setting was applied running git config --global http.proxy

Additional information:

```
git config
```

Comment: What do I have to replace at \vsilva:Passw0rd? Do I have to replace domain.local with my local IPv4 address?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command

`git config --global --unset https.proxy`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to override the SSH settings.

```
$ vim ~/.ssh/config

# You can also manually open the file and copy/paste the section below
# Add section below to it
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Then try

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi ! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
provide shell access.
```

Now try

```
git push -u origin master
```

This should be successful!!!

For more information check the reference : [Click Here](https://gist.github.com/Tamal/1cc77f88ef3e900aeae65f0e5e504794)